android webview camera - NotReadableError
When call camera in Javascript
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false});
I got Error Popup
"NotReadableError : Could not start video source"
(but camera is running on webview)
Also it works with no error sometimes..
My webview code is..
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        // Grant permissions for cam
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPermissionRequest");
            mPermissionRequest = request;
            final String[] requestedResources = request.getResources();
            for (String r : requestedResources) {
                if (r.equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE)) {
                    // In this sample, we only accept video capture request.
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Allow Permission to camera")
                            .setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    mPermissionRequest.grant(mPermissionRequest.getResources()); // new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE}
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Granted");
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    mPermissionRequest.deny();
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Denied");
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequestCanceled(PermissionRequest request) {
            super.onPermissionRequestCanceled(request);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
  });
  myWebView.loadUrl("My URL");
}

